# Download for Windows XP Service Packs

Tags: windows, windows-xp, service-pack, sp3, sp2

It appears that at the moment, the Service Packs for Windows XP have been pulled from Microsoft's website. Right now I am trying to upgrade to SP3 on an offline PC, which means I also need SP1/SP2. Does anybody have links to SP1/SP2 and SP3? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are plenty of disk-image sharing sites, like allbootdisks, that host files that are no longer managed / hosted by microsoft.

Comment: Unfortunately all I can find there is boot floppies.

Comment: There's an iso on there somewhere. I've used them before. You can convert an img. to an .iso. There's plenty of guides if you need one.

Comment: To get the two most recent XP updates (as of 6/19/17) use these two links:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55245 and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=18770

Answer (score 3):

Service Packs are cumulative, which means SP2 contains all the updates in SP1 and SP3 contains all the updates in SP1 and SP2.

So if you want to update Windows XP, you only need SP3.

MajorGeeks.com has been a reliable mirror for me in the past and they have the final release of SP3 - here: http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/microsoft_windows_xp_service_pack_3.html

Comment: Worth pointing out that SP3 was the only version Microsoft supported which means any Microsoft Software recently released requires SP3, if you are going to use Windows XP despite the huge amount of security vulnerabilities it has, please only use SP3.

Comment: In order to install SP3, I need a minimum of SP1 already installed.

Comment: @Noodly_Doodly intergate the Sp3 into an ISO, here you don't need it. Use nlite to do this.

Comment: @magicandre1981 If as in add it to the Windows XP install CD, I cannot reinstall Windows XP right now.

Comment: I have not tested it, but this seems to be a mirror for SP1 - http://www.download3k.com/Install-Windows-XP-Service-Pack-1-SP1.html

Comment: @Touff From what I can see, download3k has been reviewed as untrustworthy.

Comment: @Noodly_Doodly lol you've got me scouring the internet for SP1 now! I found it on FilePlanet, should be legit - again can't say for certain though... http://www.fileplanet.com/112826/download/Windows-XP-Service-Pack-1

Answer (score 0):

All updates (packs and standalone) are available for download directly from Microsoft at the following address, even if the old links have been removed from the support sites:
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx
You can search for a specific KB number, or just use "XP Service Pack 3" in the search box. It will return the initial Service Pack 3 update, but also all subsequent updates released afterwards to improve on SP3!